# Azure Linux VM + ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, linux, azure

I built an ASP.NET core application, running on Azure Linux VM.

I managed to get start the application by login in (via SSH) to the VM and using the `dotnet run` command.

The problem is that the asp.net application getting shut down once i close log out (close the SSH).

How do you keep the application running even if the SSH is closed?

Comment: Do you try `dotnet run &`? Use `&` to run your commands background.

Comment: Hey Walter, using `dotnet run &` yelds `[1] 2592`, but i can't seem to be able to connect to any of the controller endpoints

Comment: What do your mean?  `&` is added to the end of your command. Sorry for my mistake, what is your full commands? Add `&` to the end of your full commands.

Comment: THis is what i see when using `dotnet run &` http://imgur.com/a/PRREc , the only command i run is this

Comment: `ps -ef|grep dotnet` what is the result? The process is running in the backgroup, so you could not see it.

Comment: Doing so get me this: http://imgur.com/a/vn62s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143067/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-user6079392).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `&` to the end of your command. The `&` makes the command run in the background. Even you close your ssh session, your application is also running.

**Answer**: Using `sudo nohup dotnet run &` worked.

From `man bash`

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.